# redirect to another html file using php

Tags: php, html

I currently want to redirect to another HTML file (i.e. dashboard.html) after the user has successfully. I know I can use header to solve this, but I am not sure where should I add it into my code.

```
if (mysqli_query($Link, $Query)) {
        $lastID = mysqli_insert_id($Link);
        $Query2 = "INSERT INTO $table_2 VALUES (NULL,
        '".$lastID."')";
        if (mysqli_query($Link, $Query2)) {
            $message = "You've sucessfully created the account!";
            echo json_encode(array('success'=>'true', 'action'=>'login','html'=>$message, 'console.log'=>$Query));
        }
        else {
            $message = "Error occur in query2";
            echo json_encode(array('action'=>'error','html'=>$message, 'console.log'=>$Query));
        }
    }
    else {
        $message = "Error in query1";
        echo json_encode(array('action'=>'error','html'=>$message, 'console.log'=>$Query));
    }
```

Cheers for your kindly help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (mysqli_query($Link, $Query)) {
        $lastID = mysqli_insert_id($Link);
        $Query2 = "INSERT INTO $table_2 VALUES (NULL,
        '".$lastID."')";
        if (mysqli_query($Link, $Query2)) {
            $message = "You've sucessfully created the account!";
            echo json_encode(array('success'=>'true', 'action'=>'login','html'=>$message, 'console.log'=>$Query));
        }
        else {
            $message = "Error occur in query2";
            echo json_encode(array('action'=>'error','html'=>$message, 'console.log'=>$Query));
        }
    }
    else {
        $message = "Error in query1";
        echo json_encode(array('action'=>'error','html'=>$message, 'console.log'=>$Query));
    }
```

---

**jQuery**

```
$.ajax( { 
    type: 'POST', 
    dataType: 'json', 
    data: postData, 
    url: 'n3228691.scm.tees.ac.uk/Yii/MACC/models/…';, 
    success: function(data) { 
        console.log(data); 
        if(data.action === "login"){
            window.location="dashboard.html"; //succeed insert
        }else{
            alert('There was an error handling your registration!'); 
        }
    }, 
    error: function(data) { 
        alert('There was an error handling your registration!'); 
    }
});
```

Comment: @JasonLau could you post a sample of it? You should do the redirect after succesfull on ajax then.

Comment: $.ajax( {
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: "json",
    data: postData,    
    url: 'https://n3228691.scm.tees.ac.uk/Yii/MACC/models/class.model.registerUser.php?action=register',
      
    success: function(data) {
     console.log(data);
     $('<div></div>').html(data.html).appendTo('.msg');
     //$.mobile.loading('hide');
     window.location="https://n3228691.scm.tees.ac.uk/Yii/MACC/gallery1.html";
    },
      
    error: function(data) {
     alert('There was an error handling your registration!');
    }
   });

Comment: cheers. But I am wondering what is the purpose of the action in my php code?

Comment: The `action` key simply told that if the data successfully inserted to database with value `login` and prints `error` if the insertion failed.

Comment: Is the code working properly? Could you accept this as an answer? :D

Answer (score 0):

You can either add an `<a>` tag into the code built by PHP:

```
<a href="new_page.php">Click this link for new page</a>
```

Or, you can use javascript/jQuery to trap a user click and redirect them to a new page:

```
<div id="redir">Click this link</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function(){
        $('#redir').click(function(){
            window.location.href = 'new_page.php'
        });
    });
</script>
```

Or, if headers have already been sent and the PHP `header()` method specified in joakkinen's answer won't work, you can echo this HTML:

```
echo '<meta HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" content="0; url=new_page.php">';
```

*(the content=0 represent number of seconds delay before redirect)*

Comment: if (mysqli_query($Link, $Query2)) {
            $message = "You've sucessfully created the account!";
            echo json_encode(array('success'=>'true', 'action'=>'login','html'=>$message, 'console.log'=>$Query));
            header('Location: dashboard.htmll');
        }

Comment: Okay, I didn't understand that you were part way through a transaction. In that case, joakkinen has the answer except that the `header()` method only works if no  other headers have been sent. If they have, then you can echo HTML to the page like this:  `echo '<meta HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" content="0; url=new_page.php">';` *(the `content=0` represent number of seconds delay before redirect)*

Answer (score 0):

I can add ...

```
header('Location: dashboard.html');
exit;
```

Comment: i have tried this and tested by the firebug. However, the HTML code can be displayed  there, but it just cant display it